# Subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\Bbb R/K$ is finite.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Is there a field $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $1 < [\mathbb{R} : K] < \infty$?
i.e a proper subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the field extension $\mathbb{R}/K$ is finite.

Comment: Note that $K$ must be uncountable.

Comment: And every element of $\mathbb R\setminus K$ must be algebraic.

Comment: Looks like you'd need to adjoin a set of positive measure to $\mathbb{Q}$ as a basis

Comment: Is there any elemantary proof for nonexistence ?

Comment: A very natural question, but as @Timbuc’s answer points out, Artin-Schreier forbids such a field. Do you know the proof that $\mathbb R$ has no nontrivial automorphisms? It’s much more basic than A-S, and you can prove it yourself. It demonstrates the weaker proposition that there are no fields $K$ over which $\mathbb R$ is normal.

Comment: @Lubin that is a nice remark. Do you think this approach might be extended to obtain a proof of the full proposition?

Comment: @MarcoFlores, no, I think the two facts are independent, even if of a similar flavor. You can prove, by a philosophically similar method, that the $p$-adic fields $\mathbb Q_p$ also have no nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: Related (but different): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140259

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Artin-Schreier](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) theorem implies that $\;[\Bbb C:K]\le2\;$ , and from here that the answer is **no** .